# Angular realm/mongo Watch of collection as observable array

Tags: angular, mongodb, realm, watch

I'm trying to get a observable array from the realm watch option to display the data in a table.
The code does compile but the result is empty(data from the collection isn't empty).

```
  watchAccounts(): Observable<AccountDTO[]> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.#accCollection
        .find({
          status: 30,
          sort: 25
        })
        .then(accs => {
          console.log('result: ', accs);
          if (accs) {
            observer.next(accs);
          }
          const usrStream = this.#accCollection.watch();
          usrStream
            .next(stream => {
              stream.onNext(update => observer.next(update.fullDocument));
              stream.onError(err => observer.error(err));
              observer.add(() => {
                stream.close();
              });
            })
            .catch(err => console.error('Error in stream: ', err.message));
        });
    });
  }
```

When debugging it won't go past the first line.

This does work but i want a observable as result:

```
  watchUser2(): void {
    this.#accCollection
      .find({
        status: 30,
        sort: 25
      })
      .then(accs => {
        console.log('result: ', accs);
        if (accs) {
        }
        const usrStream = this.#accCollection.watch();
        usrStream
          .next(stream => {
            stream.onNext(update => console.log(update)); //observer.next(update.fullDocument)
            stream.onError(err => console.error(err.message)); //observer.error(err)
            // observer.add(() => {
            //   stream.close();
            // });
          })
          .catch(err => console.error('Error in stream: ', err.message));
      });
  }
```

Comment: If you add a breakpoint to your code and step through it line by line inspecting execution and vars along the way, what line is not executing like you would expect?

Comment: The breakpoint won't even go to the 2nd line, when i remove the 'new Observable'  and just execute the query it does work